# What statistical test to use for comparing result between two treatment types

Tags: group-differences

I want to study the difference in inflammatory response in subjects receiving the drug Pioglitazone versus placebo measured as plasma hsCRP level (a continuous value). I also want to adjust this with baseline parameters like, gender, age, BMI etc. Can someone please help me what statistical test is suitable for this problem.

Comment: Are you using data from a randomized controlled trial? In that case you can just follow the methods outlined in the study protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Subjects are randomized in a double-blind fashion to receive either the treatment pioglitazone, or placebo. There are differences in baseline parameters. So I want to adjust it as well. Can you kindly specify which statistical method is suitable for this analysis?